# How to create a dataframe programmatically from scratch?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to pandas. I am used to SQL, XML and json. Pandas seems very different to traditional data structure.

I am trying to scrape a website and create a dataframe from it.
Here is the code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url='some.webpage.com'
response = requests.get(url)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
urlDivs = soup.select(".urlDiv")

df = pd.DataFrame ({'Link' : [], 'Title':[]})
for urlDiv in urlDivs:
    Link = urlDivs urlDivs.select_one(".url").attrs.get("href")
    Title = urlDivs.select_one(".title").get_text()
    df.insert(Link, Title)
```

The code doesn't run. It says the value is missing. But no matter how i add 'Link': Link, using append and concat, the code just doesn't run.

I checked Pandas documentation. It seems to me they Pandas creates dataframe from columns. It cannot add data row by row? I cannot find any related syntax and get very confused.

Comment: "It says the value is missing" What says what value is missing? Please [edit] to include the full error traceback as well as the output of a few loops of `print(link, title)` r similar so we can better understand, since we can't check 'some.webpage.com'

Comment: Also you can add rows to a dataframe with `pd.concat()`

Comment: *It says the value is missing* a bit vague, isn't it? Would be great, if you could improve your question with details and clarity, it would be easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.insert()` method is only used to insert columns, not rows.

However, `pandas` excepts lists as columns, so your code could be rewritten to:

```py
links = []
titles = []
for urlDiv in urlDivs:
    links.append(jobEntry.select_one(".url").attrs.get("href"))
    titles.append(jobEntry.select_one(".title").get_text())

df = pd.DataFrame ({'Link': links, 'Title': titles})
```

Or if you wish to use something like append:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame ({'Link' : [], 'Title':[]})
for urlDiv in urlDivs:
    Link = jobEntry.select_one(".url").attrs.get("href")
    Title = jobEntry.select_one(".title").get_text()
    pd.concat((df, pd.DataFrame({'Link': Link, 'Title': Title})), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: so if I only want to add one row, I would use the concat function you suggested?

Comment: @TrioCheung If you want to add one row at a time, yes.

Comment: is it possible to create an empty dataframe? I need to create a loop for my concat program

Comment: i just saw other discussions. I just realised dataframe is supposedly never modified